# Sharing data between directives AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

I have been trying out some AngularJS tutorials and dabbling around trying to create a simple website.

I have a directive that creates a side navigation bar and populates the list of items from some json data stored on my server. The name list is populated without an issue.

The problem is that I need to share that name between several controllers, but I am not having any luck doing so.

My `app.js` contains:

```
var app = angular.module("Myapp", ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.service('nameService', function() {
    var name = "";

    this.setName = function(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    this.getName = function() {
        return name;
    }
});

app.directive("sideBar",  ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: "views/sidebar.html",

        controller: function($scope) {

            $scope.updateName = function(name) {
                alert(name);
            };  

            $http.get('../data/names.json').
                success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.names = data;
            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) { });          
        }
    };
}]);
```

From what I've read you should just be able to inject the service as a dependency as follows:

```
app.directive("sideBar",  ['$http', 'nameService', function($http, nameService) {
```

Then I should be able to update the value like so:

```
 $scope.updateName = function(name) {
     nameService.setName(name);
 };
```

However, when I try to inject the dependency it breaks the entire directive and the sidebar will no longer load.

I have been pulling my hair out trying to figure out why it breaks without much luck. Is there something I am missing? Or am I going about this the complete wrong way?

Comment: Just some failproof first:

In your index.html, do you load your service javascript *before* your directive javascript?

If you do, it shouldn't break the directive at all. Keep us informed!

Comment: general approach is correct

Comment: @GabrielPires This is all contained in my app.js file. I have yet to break things apart. Index.html includes the app.js

Comment: @GabrielPires that's not really an issue, no injection gets done until after app bootstraps

Comment: @charlietfl do you have any suggestions why my sidebar breaks when I try to inject the nameService as a dependency?

Comment: You guys are right, my bad =).

But here, I made a simple jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/pcrp9omw/1/) with the code you provided, even included the service injection. It does not break at all, as expected.

Can you elaborate more, or check the differences in that fiddle?

Comment: @redFIVE not really, perhaps you could make demo in plnkr.co with code you are using and see what happens there and if it breaks share the link

Comment: @GabrielPires it worked after copy and pasting your jsfiddle code... I'm at a loss as to why it never worked originally, but it does now, thanks for your time regardless!

Comment: Well, it isn't nice when we don't get why something wasn't working, but always look at the bright side, it is working now =)